# Shiny Plotly output that changes depending on conditions

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm trying to make a shiny app for some user-friendly data analysis of some data I have, and I'd like to change the outputted Plotly plot depending on which file i'm looking at. Basically, I'd like to have one plot outputted at a time, where I can cycle through several plots (that don't change place in my shiny app) depending on which folder and criteria i'm using. Currently I'm struggeling with this, and I don't know exactly what to do from here. I've attached a few images to clarify what I mean and what I want.

[This photo shows my UI and how I want my figures to be displayed. I'd like all figures to show in that same location, depending on the selected file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k5qV.png)
[image: This photo shows my UI and how I want my figures to be displayed. I'd like all figures to show in that same location, depending on the selected file.]

[When I switch to 'Datalogger', a new plot is generated, and it is outputted below the first one. I'd like it to be placed on top of it, in the exact same location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0s70.png)
[image: When I switch to 'Datalogger', a new plot is generated, and it is outputted below the first one. I'd like it to be placed on top of it, in the exact same location.]

Any help you can offer would be very welcome.

Best,
T.

Script:

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)

#picarro
time = as.character(seq(as.POSIXct("2018-06-01 12:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-06-01 12:10:00"), by=seconds() )); ch4.corr = runif(length(time), 1980, 2000);
data = data.frame(time, ch4.corr); data$time = as.POSIXct(time); 
#datalogger
time = as.character(seq(as.POSIXct("2018-06-01 12:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-06-01 12:10:00"), by=seconds() )); PressureOut = runif(length(time), 1010, 1020);
dlog = data.frame(time, PressureOut); dlog$time = as.POSIXct(time);
#dronelog
time = as.character(seq(as.POSIXct("2018-06-01 12:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-06-01 12:10:00"), by=seconds() ));
ulog = data.frame(time); ulog$time = as.POSIXct(time);

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Active AirCore analysis"),
   hr(),
   fluidRow(
      column(3,
             radioButtons("fileInput", "File",
                          choices = c("Picarro", "Datalogger", "Dronelog"),
                          selected = "Picarro"),
             hr(),
             conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.fileInput == 'Picarro'",
                sliderInput("timeInputPicarro", "Time", as.POSIXct(data$time[1]), as.POSIXct(data$time[length(data$time)]), c(as.POSIXct(data$time[1])+minutes(1), as.POSIXct(data$time[length(data$time)])-minutes(1)), timeFormat = "%H:%M:%S", ticks = T, step = seconds(1), pre = "")),
             conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.fileInput == 'Datalogger'",
                sliderInput("timeInputDatalogger", "Time", as.POSIXct(dlog$time[1]), as.POSIXct(dlog$time[length(dlog$time)]), c(as.POSIXct(dlog$time[1]), as.POSIXct(dlog$time[length(dlog$time)])), timeFormat = "%H:%M:%S", ticks = T, step = seconds(1), pre = "")),
             conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.fileInput == 'Dronelog'",
                sliderInput("timeInputDronelog", "Time", as.POSIXct(ulog$time[1]), as.POSIXct(ulog$time[length(ulog$time)]), c(as.POSIXct(ulog$time[1])+minutes(1), as.POSIXct(ulog$time[length(ulog$time)])-minutes(1)), timeFormat = "%H:%M:%S", ticks = T, step = seconds(1), pre = "")),
             hr(),
             conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.fileInput == 'Picarro'",
                radioButtons("picarroPlotInput", "Plot type",
                             choices = c("Time-series", "Process"),
                             selected = "Time-series")),
             conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.fileInput == 'Datalogger'",
                radioButtons("dataloggerPlotInput", "Plot type",
                             choices = c("Time-series", "Altitude"),
                             selected = "Time-series")),
             hr(),
             checkboxGroupInput(inputId='sidebarOptions', 
                                label=('Options'),
                                choices=c('Blabla', 'Store data', 'BlablaBla')),
             hr()),
      br(),

      mainPanel(
         plotlyOutput("dataplot"),
         hr(),
         plotlyOutput("dlogplot")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   datasetInputPic <- reactive({ data = data;  })
   datasetInputPicSamp <- reactive({ dat = data[(data$time>=input$timeInputPicarro[1]) & (data$time<=input$timeInputPicarro[2]),]; })
   datasetInputDatalogger <- reactive({ dlog = dlog })
   datasetInputDronelog <- reactive({ ulog = ulog })

   output$dataplot <- renderPlotly({
      if( (input$fileInput == 'Picarro' ) & (input$picarroPlotInput == 'Time-series')){
         data = datasetInputPic();
         data$time = as.POSIXct(data$time);
         dat = datasetInputPicSamp();
         dat$time = as.POSIXct(dat$time);

         sec.col = "red";
         f = list(size = 8);

         x <- list(title = " ")
         y <- list(title = "CH<sub>4</sub> [ppb]")
         p2 = plot_ly() %>%
            add_trace(data = data,
                      x = ~time,
                      y = ~ch4.corr,
                      type = 'scatter',
                      mode = "markers",
                      marker = list(size = 3, color = 'black')) %>%
            add_trace(data = dat,
                      x = ~time,
                      y = ~ch4.corr,
                      type = 'scatter',
                      mode = "markers",
                      marker = list(size = 3, color = sec.col)) %>%
            layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y, title = '', showlegend = F, titlefont = f);

         s1 = subplot(p2, margin = 0.06,nrows=1,titleY = TRUE) %>%
            layout(showlegend = F, margin = list(l=50, r=0, b=50, t=10), titlefont = f);
         s1
      }
   })
   output$dlogplot <- renderPlotly({
      if( (input$fileInput == 'Datalogger' ) & (input$dataloggerPlotInput == 'Time-series')){
         data = datasetInputDatalogger();
         data$time = as.POSIXct(data$time);

         x <- list(title = " ")
         y <- list(title = "Outside pressure [mbar]")
         p1 = plot_ly() %>%
            add_trace(data = data, 
                      y = ~PressureOut, 
                      x = ~time, 
                      type = 'scatter',
                      mode = "markers",  
                      marker = list(size = 3, color = 'black'));

         s1 = subplot(p1, margin = 0.07, nrows=2, titleY = TRUE, titleX = FALSE)
         layout(s1, showlegend = F, margin = list(l=100, r=100, b=0, t=100), title = "Datalogger data")
         s1
      }
   })

   outputOptions(output, c("dataplot", "dlogplot"), suspendWhenHidden = TRUE)
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Is that a minimal reproducible example?  Not many people are willing to read a wall of code. You could try to use `renderUI`'s and put the conditions needed there.

Comment: @ClaudH Sorry for that, I tried to strip it as much as possible. I've stripped it even more to make it even shorter. I'm not entirely sure how to apply the renderUI; How would I go about implementing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that in your ui you have written:

```
mainPanel(
     plotlyOutput("dataplot"),
     hr(),
     plotlyOutput("dlogplot")
  )
```

Using this structure, the "dlogplot" will always display below the "dataplot" because you essentially gave it its own position in the main panel that is below the "dataplot". One solution, if you want the plots to be displayed in the same exact spot when clicking the various buttons, is to give only one `plotlyOutput`. Next you would put conditional `if`, `else if` and `else` in `renderPlotly`. For example:

```
   output$dataplot <- renderPlotly({
  if( (input$fileInput == 'Picarro' ) & (input$picarroPlotInput == 'Time-series')){
     data = datasetInputPic();
     data$time = as.POSIXct(data$time);
     dat = datasetInputPicSamp();
     dat$time = as.POSIXct(dat$time);

     sec.col = "red";
     f = list(size = 8);

     x <- list(title = " ")
     y <- list(title = "CH<sub>4</sub> [ppb]")
     p2 = plot_ly() %>%
        add_trace(data = data,
                  x = ~time,
                  y = ~ch4.corr,
                  type = 'scatter',
                  mode = "markers",
                  marker = list(size = 3, color = 'black')) %>%
        add_trace(data = dat,
                  x = ~time,
                  y = ~ch4.corr,
                  type = 'scatter',
                  mode = "markers",
                  marker = list(size = 3, color = sec.col)) %>%
        layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y, title = '', showlegend = F, titlefont = f);

     s1 = subplot(p2, margin = 0.06,nrows=1,titleY = TRUE) %>%
        layout(showlegend = F, margin = list(l=50, r=0, b=50, t=10), titlefont = f);
     s1
  }
 else if( (input$fileInput == 'Datalogger' ) & (input$dataloggerPlotInput == 'Time-series')){
     data = datasetInputDatalogger();
     data$time = as.POSIXct(data$time);

     x <- list(title = " ")
     y <- list(title = "Outside pressure [mbar]")
     p1 = plot_ly() %>%
        add_trace(data = data, 
                  y = ~PressureOut, 
                  x = ~time, 
                  type = 'scatter',
                  mode = "markers",  
                  marker = list(size = 3, color = 'black'));

     s1 = subplot(p1, margin = 0.07, nrows=2, titleY = TRUE, titleX = FALSE)
     layout(s1, showlegend = F, margin = list(l=100, r=100, b=0, t=100), title = "Datalogger data")
     s1
  }
})
```

This code will put the "dlogplot" and the "dataplot" in the same position in your main panel. (You would also need to get rid of `output$dlogplot <- renderPlotly({...})` so that it isn't also trying to make that plot.)

Try this out and see if it works for your purposes.

Comment: That works like a charm, thanks a bunch! Exactly what I needed. @Ands.